# Converting array in to custom format

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I convert the below array in to another format as specified below:

My array:

```
var test=[{"1":"Input"},{"2":"Output"}]
```

Converted array:

```
var result=

    [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Input"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            " name": "Output"
        }
    ]
```

I tried with this code but not working.

```
var result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
  var newArray = {
    id: Object.keys(test[i])[i],
    name: test[i].name
  }
  result.push(newArray);
}
```

Comment: `Object.keys(test[i])[i]` --- explain why you access `[i]` here. Also run `console.log(Object.keys(test[i]));`

Comment: @Community: please guys let them solve this trivial problem themselves after the hint above (that would be 100 times more useful than a ready to use copy-paste answer)

Comment: To get the value ,I'm accessing Object.keys(test[i])[i]

Comment: Check the `console.log(Object.keys(test[i]));` to ensure there is `i-th` element available.

Comment: FYI, this is not JSON, this is a JavaScript array.

Comment: What do you think `Object.keys(test[i])` returns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inner array object doesn't have `name` property, so `test[i].name` will be undefined. You need to get the value using the key value. Also you can simplify your code using **[`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** instead of **[`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)** loop.

```js
var test = [{
  "1": "Input"
}, {
  "2": "Output"
}];

var res = test.map(function(v) { // iterating over array object 
  var k = Object.keys(v)[0]; // getting object keys as an array & retrieving first key
  return {
    id: k, // setting id property as key
    name: v[k] // and name property as value
  }
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(res, null, 3) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use [array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for converting an array to another array using a conversion function.

[array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) will iterate on all items and run a "conversion function" on each item.

Since your item is a key-value that looks like this: `{"1":"Input"}`, the only problem you have is that you don't know the key.

To get the keys of each object you can use the [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) method.

```
var test=[{"1":"Input"},{"2":"Output"}]; // input

var newArr = test.map(function(item){
   var key = Object.keys(item)[0]; // get the object's keys and take the only key.
   return {id: key, name: item[key]} // return the new object
});
```